# What http considers the same resource?

Tags: http, caching

[Specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html#sec13)'s talking about requests for "the same resource". But I failed to find any explanations as to what it exactly is. Is it the URL? Or probably requests with the same URL and different headers are considered as different resources? I'm using custom headers as a way to influence what's returned by the server. And seem to experience some issues because of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A URL identifies a resource, and a resource is just some chunk of information.  This article succinctly describes the two's relation:

EX:

If I were to make an Http GET request as such - GET path/to/res/file - I would either get a 200 response with the file resource in the message body, or if something went wrong, I might get something like a 404 or a 500, depending on the server implementation.

http://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/#resources

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_resource

I hope that clears it up a little for you.

Comment: So, what I was asking for is probably this: `An identifier embodies the information required to distinguish what is being identified from all other things within its scope of identification.  Our use of the terms "identify" and "identifying" refer to this purpose of distinguishing one resource from all other resources, regardless of how that purpose is accomplished (e.g., by name, address, or context).` http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986

Comment: Great link! I find this very useful.